# 12-fold way permutations

Tags: combinatorics

I'm struggling to memorise / wrap my head around the twelve-fold way of counting permutations for different scenarios.

After watching some videos, I've come up with this to help.

$$
|\text{Candy}| = x \\
|\text{Bags}| = b \\
$$

Number of arrangements = $\prod^x_{i  = 1}{a(\text{Candy}_x)}$, where $a(c):=$ the number of available bags for c.

For example, with distinct candy and bags, with no restrictions on size, each piece of candy can go into any bag. So, each candy has $b$ choices of bags, making the number of arrangements $b^x$.

When bags are limited to at most 1 piece of candy, the return value for $a$ will decrement. Which I believe will make for $\frac{m!}{(m-n)!}$

I do not know whether this simple idea holds for the more complicated sections of the 12-fold table.

Comment: A (relatively) common way to visualize the twelvefold way is placing balls in boxes. Your method seems analogous.

Comment: Same concept. I wanted to avoid confusion (with the b's in their names) so I opted for candy/bags

Comment: How are you thinking of mappings where candies and/or bags are unlabeled?

Comment: No idea... Math 2 hard